# live streaming MPEG-TS on android

Tags: android, android-videoview, live-streaming, exoplayer, mpeg

I have a UDP MPEG-TS live stream in my local network and I'm trying to display the stream on a Videoview in android.. and can't get that working.
Simply setting the url to the view doesn't work

videoview.setVideoURI(uri);

what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: If you can convert or change videostream format, what about to use HLS(Http Live streamming)? Android supports RTSP, HTTP orogressive streamming and HTTP live streamming. See this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#network

Comment: I found a good solution by using exoplayer and making the datasource.factory to an instance of UdpDataSource.Factory().

Comment: @abdulrahimalmethiab I have the same problem. could you please explain more about your solution or post a sample code here? thanks